# How can I onclick an HTML variable change?

Tags: javascript, variables, coldfusion

I am working in HTML and Coldfusion.  I want to set a variable equal to zero in CF, then have an onclick event trigger a script that changes the value in the HTML variable to a one.  Then I can run a cfif that is true if there is a one in the variable.  Does anyone know the best way to do this?  This is what I am trying, but the onClick does not trigger anything useful.

```
    <cfset dayHolder = 0>

<!--- Make a Submit Button  --->
<div style="max-width:50%; margin: auto; padding-top: 20px; text-align: center">
    <input type="button" name="submit" onclick="setupVar();" value="Submit Day Page" tooltip="Submits Your Hour by Hour"
     style="font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:16px;"/>
</div>
    <script>

    function setupVar(){
        dayHolder=1;
    return dayHolder;
    }
    </script>

    <cfoutput> #dayHolder#</cfoutput>
    <br>

     <!--- Send the data to the database --->
    <cfif 'dayHolder' eq 1> 
    etc...
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Javascript cannot execute CFML code. That requires a new http request, either using ajax or submitting a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing your ideas a little bit, Javascript runs on the clients browser while CF runs on the server, so to make the changes you are trying to make you'll need to submit a form. Here is an example that should help you:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(FORM,"dayHolder")>
    <cfset dayHolder = FORM.dayHolder>
<cfelse>
    <cfset dayHolder = 0>
</cfif>

<!--- Make a Submit Button  --->
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="dayHolder" id="dayHolder" value="0">
    <div style="max-width:50%; margin: auto; padding-top: 20px; text-align: center">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="setupVar();" value="Submit Day Page" tooltip="Submits Your Hour by Hour"
         style="font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:16px;"/>
    </div>
</form>
<script>

function setupVar(){
    document.getElementById('dayHolder').value = '1';
    return true;
}
</script>

<cfoutput> #dayHolder#</cfoutput>
<br>

 <!--- Send the data to the database --->
<cfif dayHolder eq 1>
```

*updated according to comment.

Comment: Thank you.  This did exactly what I needed.  I certainly appreciate the help and learning opportunity.

Comment: I would recommend not using `isDefined()`, though. Go with `structKeyExists(FORM,"dayHolder")` instead. That'll stop something along the lines of `mylink.cfm?FORM.dayHolder=<badStuffHere>` being written back into your page.